# ffmpeg-detect audio level from live audio streaming(php)

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i have live audio stream service. I need to use ffmpeg to check audio level of stream in real time.

i have tried

```
ffmpeg -i sample.aac -filter:a volumedetect -vn -f null /dev/null
```

I need my live audio streaming link in place of `sample.aac`.

Comment: are you using shell_exec command as displayed here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

Comment: yes, i am using shell_exec.